# Função Map com lambda em uma lista de dicionários Python

Tags: python, api, expressões-lambda

Boa noite, estou pegando os dados via API e transformando em um .JSON para gravar em uma lista:. Dentro da lsta info existe uma lista de dicionários chamada custom_fields, então utilizei map com função lambda para pegar os valores:

```
info = r.json()

gravar=[]
for infos in info['tickets']:
        gravar.append((infos['url'],
                    infos['id'],
                    infos['created_at'],
                    infos['status'],
                    infos['requester_id'],
                    infos['collaborator_ids'],
                    infos['tags'],
                    map(lambda t: t["id"], infos['custom_fields']),
                    map(lambda v: v["values"], infos['custom_fields'])
    )) 

print(gravar[0])
```

Ao invés de retornar os valores, ele está retornando dessa forma:

```
...<map object at 0x000001B3B27CEFD0>, <map object at 0x000001B3B27F0048>)
```

Como faço para listar os elementos dentro dos dicionários dessa lista?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver usando a função list:

```
list(map(lambda t: t["id"], infos['custom_fields'])),
list(map(lambda v: v["value"], infos['custom_fields']))
```

retorno:

```
...,[360022972013, 360022962034, 360022975213], [None, None, None])
```